# ReactJS PWA : calculate disk space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA based on CRA and I want to calculate the disk space on my device (desktop/mobile when PWA is installed).

There is a Javascript solution to achieve this ?
I've searched in the net but I don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this information from the PWA. You would need a native app.

Comment: But the PWA is an application opened in navigator right ? Can I have this information from the navigator ? thank you :)

Comment: PWA is a webpage with access to service workers and that's really it.